# How to Fix function not getting called when using 'OnClick' in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, perl

I'm writing a Perl script to do a POST request when clicking a button. It's a monolith code, using html and javascript with Perl. On clicking the button, the 'onclick' functionality is not somehow triggering the function 'PostRequest'. But when I am using a reference link with 'onclick' instead, that seems to be working fine.

```
$html .= CreateJiraLink();

sub Jira {
    my $args = $_;
    # This will be given from JiraInformation
    my $namedID = 'some value;
    my $teamname = 'some value';
    my $jiraname = 'some value';
    my $jiradescription = 'some value';

    my $requestData = {
                    operation => 'create',
                    named_sql_id => $namedID,
                    team_name => $teamname,
                    jira_name => $jiraname,
                    jira_description => $jiradescription
                    };
    my $requestDataJSON = JSON::encode_json($requestData);  # Encode the requestData as JSON
    # print('********* Inside CreateJira *********');
    # print ('$requestDataJSON');
    my $html = Unindent(qq|
    <script>
        function PostRequest() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'some url',
                data: $requestDataJSON,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('AJAX request successful.');
                    console.log(response);
                    // Handle the response data here
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('AJAX request error.');
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                    // Handle the error here
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    |);
    $html .= qq{<td> <button id="jirabutton" onclick="return PostRequest()">Create JIRA task</button>};
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: `<button type="button" id="jirabutton" onclick="PostRequest()">Create JIRA</button>` and remove the return. You do not get a useful return from your function you can use in the onclick

Comment: Alternatively do `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { document.getElementById("jirabutton").addEventListener("click", PostRequest); });` and remove the onclick

Comment: Is there any error in the console when you click?

Comment: if you do View Source in the browser, does the function definition look correct?